# How to Query the Status of Subreports in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting ready to upgrade an instance of SQL Server 2005.  This instance also handles some reports which will need to be moved.  I am trying to find out which reports are no longer being used (as of the last 14 months) so that they can be decommissioned.  I have been using the following query, which returns the names of reports but seems to be missing subreports.  Does anyone know of a better way?  Any help would be really appreciated.  Query follows:

```
USE ReportingServicesExecutionLog;
GO

WITH FindUsedReports AS 

(SELECT DISTINCT r.name AS [Name], 
             MAX(e.timeend) AS [Date Last Used],
             COUNT(e.ExecutionLogID) AS [Number of Times Used],
             rt.Name AS [Report Type],
             u.UserName AS [User Name],
             r.path AS [Path]
FROM dbo.Reports r
    INNER JOIN dbo.ExecutionLogs e
           ON r.ReportKey=e.ReportKey
    INNER JOIN ReportTypes rt
           ON r.ReportType=rt.ReportType
    INNER JOIN dbo.Users u
           ON e.UserKey=u.UserKey
GROUP BY r.name, u.UserName, rt.Name, r.path
)

SELECT * 
FROM FindUsedReports
WHERE [Date Last Used] <= DATEADD(mm,-14, GETDATE())
ORDER BY [Name];
```

Comment: Sample data and expected result will help us

Comment: As an example, if I had a Report called ActiveDirectoryActivity with subreports of EmployeePictures, UsersbyGroup and IndividualUsers, then I would like the query to return the information that ActiveDirectoryActivity was last used on "x" date, was used 150 times in the last 14 months, the report type, by whom, and the report path.  I'd also like it to show the subreports.  As it stands, I get all the information I mentioned except that the subreports aren't being shown.  Additionally, some of the reports which were shown as not having been used in that time actually were.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Forgive me for not posting specific sample data....I'm bound by company policy.  If there is any other clarification you need, please let me know and I'll do my best to provide it.